# request for member error when loading in customtableviewcell and setting its IBOUTLETS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I've spent the last 3 hours scratching my head at this issue because all seems correct, except I can't get through to my tableviewcell class to set the uilabels in my custom cell.

here is my code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];


            //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        //cell.imageViewSection =

        // Set up the cell
        int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

        NSString *textTitle = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];

        NSURL *imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"description"]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageurl]];



        cell.imageViewSection = image;
        cell.titleLabelText.text = textTitle;

return cell;

}
```

If someone can help me out it would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on the cell always being returned as object at index 0 in the array. Do a simple loop to find the actual cell.

And add typecasts for the cell subclass you use

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellID = @"cellID";
    MyCell* cell = (id)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" 
                                                     owner:self 
                                                   options:nil];
        for (cell in nib) {
            if ([cell isKindOfClass:[MyCell class]]) {
                break;
            }
        }
     }
     // Safely do tuff to cell
     return cell;
}
```

This snippet assumes that the cell is at least available, the behavior if no table view cell is returned is undefined.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. i'm setting the iboutlets in my tableviewcell class named TableViewCell.

When it comes to customising the cell using the 

cell.imageViewSection.image = image

I get a request for member in something not a structure or union...

Once the object is initialised i should just be able to set its values...

Comment: @MrPink - Ah, that is because `UITableViewCell` do not have the properties you try to set. You need to typecast. I extend my answer. Are you by any change MrPink of Reservoir Gods?

Comment: @MrPink - Also concider using an `UINib` instance for creating the cells. The idea is the same, but `UINib` allows the nib-file to be cached in memory for faster creation.

Comment: I am indeed Mr Pink from reservoir dogs! And thanks for your help managed to get my head round it!

Comment: @MrPink - My pleasure, I am a fan of your work on Atari Falcon.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning and casting TableViewCell to UITableViewCell variable and UITableViewCell does not have those outlets. Instead, you should do the following..

```
TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (TableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```